# Code analysis error during Check In to TFS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, .net-core

When I'm trying to check in to TFS there's an error:

`"An unexpected error occurred while evaluating the Code Analysis check-in policy. The error might be transient. Try again."` with link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-policy-errors?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vs.codeanalysis.policyfailures)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019

There is no extra information by clicking on this error. I've tried to check the requirements from the reference, but that didn't help.
The solution contains .Net Core 2.0 projects and .Net Framework 4.6.2 projects

TFS settings set Microsoft Extended Correctness Rules, project rules are the same, checkbox `"Enable Code analysis on build"` checked.
The solution was rebuilt, also I've tried to run Code Analysis on Solution with result `"Code Analysis Complete -- 0 error(s), 20 warning(s)"`
The same error happens in VS2017 and VS2019

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: It's suddenly happened? the Code Analysis Policy always was? it's occurs on any file you tried to check-in?

Comment: The Code Analysis Policy always was. It's happened on already existing solution and a new solution after initial check-in. Yes, it occurs on any file while trying to ckeck-in.